# use setTimeout with showModalDialog in chrome will block the tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, window.open, showmodaldialog

I need a function about ShowModalDialog with setTimeout,so I test about popup window 
 and ModalDialog in Google Chrome and I get some problems.
 there are two popup window showing on page load.one is opened by winodw.open(), 
 another is opened by window.showmodaldialog() like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.open("PopupWindow.html","_blank","")},100);
setTimeout(function(){window.showModalDialog("ModalDialog.html","","")},100)};
```

After two popup window were opened, I click an button on PupupWindow.html. It will call
the function as follow:

```
function test()
{
  setTimeout(function(){alert("test");},1000);
}
```

**It's work fine in Google Chrome 14**. After I update the Google Chrome to version 19, 
the PopupWindow.html will be hang when call test() until the ModalDialog.html was closed.
Please tell me why the case broken on Google Chrome 19 or any way to do showModalDialog
and window.open() on Google Chrome 19. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Chrome is actually exhibiting correct behavior.  The same behavior occurs for me in Safari as well as Firefox.

Modal dialogs by their very nature are supposed to prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the application until they complete the modal dialog.

Chrome has been plagued by a number of issues with not handling this correctly.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4202, http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16045, and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42939 for some examples.  It appears that maybe they're finally starting to clean some of these up if you're experiencing different behavior.

In general using `window.showModalDialog` should be avoided for a number of reasons that I detail here - http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/.

If you need a modal dialog I highly recommend [jQuery UI's dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).